# How to set default date picker value?

Tags: flutter, datepicker

I use date picker package to get date, this is my code

```
DatePicker(
   key: dobKey,
   setDate: _setDate,          
   customShape: StadiumBorder(
      side: BorderSide(
      color: Color(0xFFF991A0),
   )
),
```

How I can set default value? like 2019-04-15

Answer (score 0):

Use this -

```
await showDatePicker(
    context: context,
    initialDate: DateTime.now(),
    firstDate: DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 1)),
    lastDate: DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 6570)),
    initialDatePickerMode: DatePickerMode.year);
```

You can add initialDate as well as the range of possible dates.
You can also add the picker mode.

Comment: How to set a particular date as the `initialDate` ?